# How to declare a shared DataFrame in Julia for parallel computing

Tags: dataframe, parallel-processing, julia, julia-dataframe

I have a large simulation on a DataFrame `df` which I am trying to parallelize and save the results of the simulations in a DataFrame called `simulation_results`.

The parallelization loop is working just fine. The problem is that if I were to store the results in an array I would declare it as a `SharedArray` before the loop. I don't know how to declare `simulation_results` as a "shared DataFrame" which is available everywhere to all processors and can be modified.

A code snippet is as follows:

```
addprocs(length(Sys.cpu_info()))

@everywhere begin
  using <required packages>

  df = CSV.read("/path/data.csv", DataFrame)

  simulation_results = similar(df, 0) #I need to declare this as shared and modifiable by all processors 
  
  nsims = 100000

end


@sync @distributed for sim in 1:nsims
    nsim_result = similar(df, 0)
    <the code which for one simulation stores the results in nsim_result >
    append!(simulation_results, nsim_result)
end
```

The problem is that since `simulation_results` is not declared to be shared and modifiable by processors, after the loop runs, it produces basically an empty DataFrame as was coded in `@everywhere simulation_results = similar(df, 0)`.

Would really appreciate any help on this! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern for distributed computing in Julia is much simpler than what you are trying to do.

Your code should look more or less like this:

```
df = CSV.read("/path/data.csv", DataFrame)

@everywhere using <required packages>


simulation_results = @distributed (append!) for sim in 1:nsims
    <the code which for one simulation stores the results in nsim_result >
    nsim_result
end
```

Note you do not need to load `df` at every process within the Julia cluster since `@distributed` will make sure it is readable. You do not need to `@sync` neither because in my code you would use the aggregator function (`append!`).

A minimal working example (run with `addprocs(4)`):

```
@everywhere using Distributed, DataFrames
df = DataFrame(a=1:5,b=rand())
```

and now the result:

```
julia> @distributed (append!) for i in 2:5
           DataFrame(bsum=sum(df.b[1:myid()]),c=myid())
       end
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ bsum      c
     │ Float64   Int64
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │ 0.518127      2
   2 │ 0.777191      3
   3 │ 1.03625       4
   4 │ 1.29532       5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This strategy worked perfectly. It was also faster relative to the solution of converting from DF to matrix and back to DF.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your dataframe `df` is numeric in the entries you process, you can pass it back and forth as a matrix:

```
mynames = names(df)
matrix = Matrix(df)
```

Then convert matrix to to SharedArray and compute. Then back to matrix.

```
dfprocessed = DataFrame(matrix, mynames)
```

Note this method may fail if your dataframe's data are not all of uniform type. It would work best if all are integer or all floating point. You might have to first drop non-numeric columns or set those to numeric levels.

Comment: The operations described here will work even if data is not homogeneous. Just if you want to make auto-detection of column types do `identity.(DataFrame(matrix, mynames))`.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very useful direction. My ```df``` has Floats, Ints and Strings. The auto-detection technique is quite useful in this regard. 

However I think I am making a mistake in declaring the ```matrix``` as shared arrays. I tried ```matrix = SharedArrays{Any}(Matrix(df))``` but got a TypeError on worker 2 onwards : ```TypeError: in Type{...} expression, expected UnionAll, got a value of type Module```

Comment: But if ```matrix = SharedArrays{Float64}(Matrix(df))``` I got: ```ERROR: On worker 2:On worker 2:SystemError: shm_open() failed for /jl0561767X856PoLYbxXOMM1kgei: Permission denied``` which was preceded by messages for all workers,here 5 is an e.g
```From worker 5:    Requested size(MB) : 13
      From worker 5:    Please ensure requested size is within system limits.
      From worker 5:    If not, increase system limits and try again.
      From worker 5:    System max size of single shmem segment(MB) : 4
      From worker 5:    System max size of all shmem segments(MB) : 16```